# Wix: How to make an additional header sticky

Tags: velo

I am working on a site built using Wix, and facing an issue related to the site header. I need different headers for different pages on the site, however it is not possible to do so with Wix at least for now ([source](https://support.wix.com/en/article/wix-editor-request-different-header-and-footer-designs-on-different-site-pages)). So on each page where I need a header different to my site's default header, I just turned off the default header, made a `section` on top of the page as the page 'header', and put the necessary elements into it.

It works quite well so far, but I still have an issue: making this 'header' sticky. It is easy to set my site's default header sticky because there is a menu for that. However because my additional 'headers' are not really headers from Wix's point of view, I am having a problem in making those headers sticky. I was thinking of using CSS but unfortunately the feature for styling elements with CSS is not yet available to all users ([source](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/styling-elements-with-css)).

Does anyone have any idea to overcome this issue? Perhaps using Velo? Thank you very much!

Comment: you can maybe try to go back to the regular wix header, and put a state-box in it with the multiple states you need. then, using velo code, switch between the states according to the page

Comment: @yotamsha Yes last week this idea came to my mind and it worked! Thank you very much :D